# GCSFuse Provided scope(s) are not authroized error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, mount, gcsfuse

I am using gcsfuse with public access Google Cloud Storage.

When i try to mount storage with command(`gcsfuse -o allow_other --implicit-dirs bucket-name /mnt/my_directory`), i can see below messages.

```
2021/10/22 09:08:46.859250 Using mount point: /mnt/my_directory
2021/10/22 09:08:46.876966 Opening GCS connection...
2021/10/22 09:08:47.408667 Mounting file system "bucket-name"...
2021/10/22 09:08:47.410248 File system has been successfully mounted.
```

But after that, when i try to store my file in mounted directory, there was an error like below.

```
 [ERROR] Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Provided scope(s) are not authorized",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Provided scope(s) are not authorized",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
     when initiating an upload to gs://my_bucket/static/dir/1211/53714/
```

How can i fix this problem? It worked fine until 3 days ago, but suddenly it didn't work, so I'm embarrassed.

Comment: From the error message, it looks more related with [the auth scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) of the client you're using than authorization access to the bucket you're uploading to. How are you creating the credentials for GCSfuse? Make sure you're including the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope.

Comment: If you are running this on Compute Engine, the default scope has Cloud Storage **write** disabled. Edit your instance and enable writes. This requires stopping the VM instance to make this change.

Comment: @JohnHanley I solved problem. I checked k8s node pool's scope. They didn't have cloud storage write access. When i fixed it, i solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error might be caused by the `allow_other` command. It is used to override the [access permissions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) of FUSE.

> As a security measure, fuse itself restricts file system access to the user who mounted the file system (cf. fuse.txt). For this reason, gcsfuse by default shows all files as owned by the invoking user. Therefore, you should invoke gcsfuse as the user that will be using the file system, not as the root.
>
> If you know what you are doing, you can override these behaviors with the `allow_other` mount option supported by fuse and with the --uid and --gid flags supported by gcsfuse. Be careful, this may have security implications!

If you read the [description of the command](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a33f32244d8550da8b4a26e277ce07d5c6d158b5/Documentation/filesystems/fuse.txt#L100-L105) you will find:

> ##### `allow_other`
>
> This option overrides the security measure restricting file access
> to the user mounting the filesystem.  This option is by default only
> allowed to the root, but this restriction can be removed with a
> (userspace) configuration option.

I think you are getting an out of scope message either because you have not specified the --uid (user id) and the --gid (group id) flags along with the `allow_other` command or because you have not set up a userspace yet to properly override root permissions with this command If you do not need to use root access, I would simply remove this part of the command and try again.

Another possible cause I found in a [question related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632474/access-denied-provided-scopes-are-not-authorized-error-when-trying-to-make) to the error `403` was that the bucket or the objects inside of it did not have the correct Access Control system. You mentioned you are using [public access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) Google Cloud Storage, but please consider that your bucket might not have the correct access permissions as well.